# connecting sql server using vpn

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection, connection-string, vpn

Can anyone tell me how to make connection in webconfig file (which don't require an explicit connection to VPN) i.e. what I am trying that I just make connection string that either execute a code that make a connection to a vpn and then it connects to sql server in that vpn?

Right now I can connect to sql in VPN but before that I connect to VPN on my machine and then I can do my stuff, and I don't want to do this ...

---

it's not possible to do it ...

the only way is the one I have already mentioned above ...

Comment: Sorry: pretty sure the answer to your question is "not possible".

Comment: i had samething in my mind but just want to make sure ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not possible, because vpn are private network and web is open network for all and through web any body can enter ...